# VB.NET MSACCESS OLEDB Exception Unhandled Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. but my statement is correct

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I get this error when I run my program

> OLEDB Exception Unhandled Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

but I can't spot the error

This is my code:

```
Dim pictureData As Byte()
    Using ms As New MemoryStream
        PICPictureBox.Image.Save(ms, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        pictureData = ms.ToArray()
    End Using
    strsql1 = "insert into criminallist (CC#, FIRSTNAME, MIDDLENAME, LASTNAME, QUALIFIERS, ALIAS, GENDER, LASTKNOWNADDRESS, CRIMINALACTIVITY, CRIMINALINVOLVEMENT, AREAOFOPERATION, ISSUINGCOURT, REMARKS, DATEOFJAIL, TRACKERTEAM, PIC)values(@a0,@a1,@a2,@a3,@a4,@a5,@a6,@a7,@a8,@a9,@a10,@a11,@a12,@a13,@a14,@a15)"
    acscmd1.CommandText = strsql1
    acscmd1.Connection = acsconn1
    acscmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a0", CC_TextBox.Text)
    acscmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a1", FIRSTNAMETextBox.Text)
    acscmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a2", MIDDLENAMETextBox.Text)
    acscmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a3", LASTNAMETextBox.Text)
    acscmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a4", QUALIFIERSComboBox.SelectedItem)
    acscmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a5", ALIASTextBox.Text)
    acscmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a6", GENDERComboBox.SelectedItem)
    acscmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a7", LAST_KNOWN_ADDRESSTextBox.Text)
    acscmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a8", CRIMINAL_ACTIVITYTextBox.Text)
    acscmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a9", CRIMINAL_INVOLVEMENTTextBox.Text)
    acscmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a10", AREA_OF_OPERATIONTextBox.Text)
    acscmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a11", ISSUING_COURTTextBox.Text)
    acscmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a12", REMARKSTextBox.Text)
    acscmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a13", DateTimePicker1.Value.Date)
    acscmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a14", TRACKER_TEAMTextBox.Text)
    acscmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a15", pictureData)
    acscmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
    acscmd1.Dispose()
    MessageBox.Show("ADDED")
```

Comment: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Answer (score 2):

Obviously your statement is not correct or you would not be getting that error message.  The issue is with the name of the first column.  You can't have spaces or other special characters in a column name in SQL code without escaping it.  That's done for Access using brackets, i.e.

```sql
insert into criminallist ([CC#], FIRSTNAME
```

A better option is to not use spaces, special characters or reserved words in column names or any other identifiers.

Comment: I wonder whether they will then encounter the same error with `ALIAS` as a field name.

Comment: @HansUp, certainly worth considering but "Alias" is not an [Access reserved word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SQL-Reserved-Words-B899948B-0E1C-4B56-9622-A03F8F07CFC8).

Comment: Is it also a problem that there are no spaces between the parentheses and the keyword 'values'?  I'm not familiar enough with Access to know if that matters.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway, no, spaces aren't required except between keywords and/or identifiers. The lack of spaces within the second set of parentheses is no more a problem.

Comment: I was referring to the closing parenthesis of the list of columns and the keyword 'values'.  In other words, does there need to be spaces before and after the keyword `values`?  i. e. does this `)values(` need to be `) values (`?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway, I understood that and that's what I addressed, although I may not have worded it very well. What I meant is that you never need to include spaces if omitting them can't change the meaning of the code. In the case you mention, parentheses cannot be part of a keyword or identifier so they cannot be interpreted in any way other than the end of the column list and the start of the value list. Similarly, omitting spaces within the value list is no issue because those commas can't be interpreted any other way.

Comment: As a further example, starting that SQL with `insert into criminallist(` is not a problem because the opening parenthesis can't possibly be part of the table name identifier. On the other hand, using `insert intocriminallist (` would be a problem because `intocriminallist` is a valid identifier, so the interpreter won't automatically assume that the "into" part should be a keyword.